Distribution of correlation coefficient under general bivariate gaussian distribution
Suppose {$X_{i1},X_{i2}$}, $i\in [n]$ are sampled independently from normal distribution $N(\mu,\Sigma)$. Let $X\in\mathbb R^{n\times2} $ be a random matrix with i-th row equal to {$X_{i1},X_{i2}$}. The first column of $X$ is denoted as $X_{,1}$ and similarly for the second column. Define the correlation $r$ as:
$$r=\frac{(X_{,1}^\top X_{,2})}{\|X_{,1}\|_2\|X_{,2}\|_2},$$
the distribution of $r$ for $\mu=0$ is well-studied, is there any general result for distribution for $r$ when $\mu\neq 0$. For example,  if I want to compute the second moment $E(r^2)$, is there any explicit/approximated expression for it?
